# JPanel background color spills out of borders on some border types

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

When setting a border to a JPanel (in my case Titled border + Line border, but also appears on some other borders, the background color of JPanel will spill out making it look ugly as hell. Here's a demonstration:

[image: Ugliest thing I've enet seen]

The only way i can make it look normal is to create another JPanel behind this one, make it white and make this one transparent:

[image: That's way better]

So is there a way i can fix this or is it just how Swing works?

By the way, for changing background of a JPanel, i call

`panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);`,

To set the border i call

`panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(169, 169, 169)), "Settings", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));`

and as LaF, i use Windows10's LaF.

Comment: Seen this too, I thought this was the default, ty :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Title is part of the `JPanel` so the area behind it is painted with the background color. 
Using `TitledBorder.BELOW_TOP` makes it look like:

[image]